# Tradução Script SQL para Oracle

Tags: oracle

Tenho o script abaixo no SQL Server, mas preciso montá-lo no Oracle. Não conheço nada de Oracle e não consegui fazer funcionar. Poderiam me ajudar?
Oracle: 11.2.0.4.0

**Script SQL:**

```
DECLARE @DataExec datetime
DECLARE @DataRef datetime

SET @DataExec = '20161008'
set @DataRef = '20101205'

Select datediff(dd, @DataExec, Max(DatBase)) as DiasDiferenca,  
    max(DatBase) as DataLimite,
    count(1) as Qtde_Registros
from Tabela
where datbase <=@DataRef
```

**Tentativa Script Oracle:**

```
VAR DataExec date
VAR DataRef date

Exec :DataExec := to_date('20161008','YYYYMMDD')
Exec :DataRef := to_date('20101205','YYYYMMDD')

Select (:DataExec - max(DATBASE)) as DiasDiferenca,  
    max(DATBASE) as DataLimite,
    count(1) as Qtde_Registros
from DELQMST 
where DATBASE <= :DataRef;
```

Erro:

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got DATE

Answer (score 1):

```
/* caducou , mas pode servir a alguém como exemplo 
   as variaveis de retorno deveriam ter um vd_....
   mas mantive os mesmos nomes,
   Sem teste todavia */
DECLARE 

 vd_DataExec date;
 vd_DataRef date;
 
 DiasDiferenca number;
 DataLimite date;
 Qtde_Registros number;
BEGIN
 vd_DataExec := to_date('20161008','YYYYMMDD');
 vd_DataRef := to_date('20101205','YYYYMMDD');

 Select (vd_DataExec - max(DatBase), 
        max(DatBase), 
        count(1)
 INTO DiasDiferenca,
      DataLimite,
      Qtde_Registros
 from Tabela 
 where datbase <= vd_DataRef;
 
 /*faz alguma coisa*/
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente:

```
v_DataExec timestamp(3) v_DataRef timestamp(3)

v_DataExec := '20161008' v_DataRef := '20101205'

Select Max - v_DataExec as DiasDiferenca,
max(DatBase) as DataLimite, count(1) as Qtde_Registros from Tabela where datbase <=v_DataRef
```

Comment: não funcionou: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
SQL parse error location

Comment: no **select Max** eu alterei para **select Max(datBase)**

Answer (score 0):

Tente dessa maneira:

```
SELECT (TO_DATE('20161008', 'YYYYMMDD') - MAX(DatBase)) AS diasdiferenca
      ,MAX(DatBase) AS datalimite
      ,COUNT(1) AS qtde_registros
  FROM DELQMST
 WHERE datbase <= TO_DATE('20101205', 'YYYYMMDD')
```

Comment: David, DatBase não é a data do sistema. Mas a data base dos registros que desejo selecionar.

Comment: Fiz a alteração, em SQL Server acredito que seja, `getDate()`, teste agora.

Comment: dessa forma eu consegui que funcione. Eu quero fazer isso através do script.

Comment: @Marcio, pode explicar o contexto do seu objetivo?